# How to create toggle menu item in Qt 5.6

Tags: qt, qmenu

I need to have a Show/Hide item in a Qt menu, so that when a user click `Hide`  a certain widget is hidden and the menu item change to `Show`, and likewise if the user click `Show` the widget is shown and the menu item change to `Hide`. How can this be achieved in Qt 5.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to your `QMenu` some `QAction` with `setCheckable(true)` function. After that you can use SIGNAL/SLOT method to do what you want for example:

**.H file:**

```
    <...>
    QAction *_togAct;
    <...>
public slots:
    void change(bool set);
```

**.CPP file:**

```
void YourClass::change(bool set)
{
    if(set) {
        _togAct->setText("Show");
        <...>
    }
    else {
        _togAct->setText("Hide");
        <...>
    }
}
```

**Somewhere in class:**

```
_togAct = new QAction(tr("Hide"), this);
_togAct->setCheckable(true);
connect(_togAct, &QAction::toggled, this, &YourClass::change);
men->addAction(_togAct);
```